# Is it possible to get Sys.UI.DomEvent from jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radeditor

I'm trying to call Telerik (rich text 3rd party) control function directly from my Javascript.

So far I figured:

When click on the element, `_onToolBarClick: function (e)`
    is called and the argument "e" is `Sys.UI.DomEvent` which has bunch of properties that are used later.

I tried to call this method from my own Javascript code:

```
$(item).click(function (e) {
    self.options.radEditor._toolAdapter._onToolBarClick(e)
});
```

Now the "e" being passed here is  `jQuery.Event`

Is there a way to make jQuery event object into Sys.UI.DomEvent object?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a click on a given RadEditor button use its fire() method:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-fire.html
Here is a list with the commands (tools): http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-toolbar-intro.html